# jquery file stops page title from showing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `.js` file which i include like:

```
<script src="<?php echo $Settings_PathName; ?>/includes/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

inside this file is just normal Javascript codes and functions however it stops my `<title>` tag from displaying the page title in the browser window.

As soon as i remove this link, the browser title works fine.

i have also tried removing the code from this `.js` file and uploading it to the website, but it still causes the same issue

Comment: Does the page content after title is loaded ?

Comment: Where exactly you place the `script` tag - before or after `title` tag?

Comment: What does the script tag look like on the output page? (after php rendered)

Comment: Make sure the js file you're using is the official one downloaded from the jquery site.

Comment: Does the javascript work expected? Are you sure that script is loaded? See HTML that is loaded on the browser (on Chrome, right click on the page > see source) and see if the jquery file is loaded properly using a dev tools, e.g. Chrome's one https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles

Comment: the rest of the HTML is working fine, its just the `<title>` tag that is not working but its displaying fine in the source code. the `jquery.js` file is just my own functions, i have included the jquery version directly from the jquery website

Comment: That's an odd behavior, can you share some more code? Perhaps the contents inside `<head></head>` after PHP has executed?

Comment: Could you paste your jquery.js file (which is not the jquery library) inside this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/686ogee4/ , Update it and show us your JS code.

Comment: show us your js file!!  if you dont want, at least replace that php script with your static location to isolate the problem.

Comment: I am sure there is some problems with generated html. Without seeing your page nobody can help.

Comment: What value does $Settings_PathName have? How does the html look like between <head> and </head> ?

Comment: To give it a shot: are you using Yoast or similar plugin? I saw this odd behavior before with WP.

Answer (score 9):

Your html seems good, it's probably an PHP error.
If the echo doesn't work, your  element can be broken...

first, check your html, it should look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $Settings_PathName; ?>/includes/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hello world</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your browser, open the dev tools (press f12 key).
In the network panel, you should find your js file in HTTP Status = 200 or 304.
If the status = 404 or 500, the script url is wrong.

Else, open the page source (ctl+u) and check the HTML source code write by the php server.

Otherwise, check your php server:

remove the  element and replace `<h1>hello world</h1>` by `<h1><?php echo "hello world"; ?></h1>`

If it doesn't work, open your server error log and try to find the issue.

---

Another simple solution, replace your path by a CDN path :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

With a [CDN](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) you can increase your page loading speed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the php is causing the error or else you would have seen an error page stating that your variable is undefined or something similar, and if the value of this variable is empty, your js file won't load, but it won't cause the title to stop working.

It's a wild guess without really seeing the code, but try these things:

1- make sure your title tag is closed properly

2- make sure the script is AFTER the title closing tag inside the head tag

3- if that still didn't work, and if the `js` file doesn't necessarily required pre-render, put the script tag immediately before `</body>` tag this should stop that behaviour from happening.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Move your .js file out of the folder and Try following code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $Settings_PathName; ?>/includes/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
Nothing to display
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the ideas here can help, but let's start really simple. On strange behavior of generated code I tend to use "view source" to look at EXACTLY what is being generated. "Inspect element" may work as well. For extra big and complex code I can copy/paste it into a file to pass to an HTML validation service.